# iOS:development with xcode and phonegap

Tags: xcode, cordova

I am in a critical situation. I am a new iOS developer.Few days earlier I downloaded xcode 4.3.3 with student Id(free of cost). I developed a very simple app with phone-gap. It is working well in my Mac book(simulator). When i want to run this app in my iPhone,it shows certification error. To get certificate i have an apple id(iOS developer account-$99). Now i have apple developer id.So my question is that-

- Should i download `xcode` again with apple developer id because previous one is for student id?
- I would like to run my app on my iPhone without going through iTunes. How can I do this?

So,what is the optimized solution?

Comment: You need to add your mobile device to the provisioning profile in the Apple developer account this can also be done through the Organizer in xcode. Once done you need to set the correct code signing in the build settings. Default is the "Team iOS provisioning profile". Apple do have a guide for this in the actual provisioning profile area on the Apple account. Also there is documentation that can accessed through the organizer about it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no need at all you just need to register your phone with that developer id and then sign your application with correct provision . that's all you need to do. (xcode have exact build for unregistered and registered users)